# jQuery - replace multiple currency symbols from string

Tags: jquery

I hope this question isn't too basic.

I have a strings like

1. "$1.11"
2. "£1.50"
3. "15,16 €"

Is it possible to remove the currency symbols like `'$,€,£'` character from the string within single `string.replace('$', '');`.

I don't want to use multiple cases or switch case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "$1.00, £2.00, €3.00";
var newStr = str.replace(/[\$£€]/g, '');
alert(newStr);
```

As you can see, you can use a regex expression to remove all the symbols.

It currently replaces $, £, and € - but if there are others you can add each individual symbol between the [square brackets]